# Detect if the browser supports position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any reliable method to detect if the browser supports `position fixed`?

I've found some solutions but none of them seems to work well on all browsers.

Comment: You mean something for a *sticky footer* or similar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While developing a mobile application with jQuery Mobile I had the same problem. The headers should have fixed position (if supported by the browser) and the solution was to set the headers with a default `position: fixed` on the css and checked the supported property through the following method:

```
function isPositionFixedSupported() {
    return $( '[data-role="header"]' ).css( 'position' ) === 'fixed';
}
```

The returned value is `static` if not supported by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This code works completely fine. Just tested it on a Windows ME box with IE6, returns 'null' because IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed;`.

*by the way, this is NOT originally my code. ALL credits go to* [Kangax's Github](http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED) *who has many functions there to test browser features.*

```
function () {
  var container = document.body;
  if (document.createElement &&
  container && container.appendChild && container.removeChild) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    if (!el.getBoundingClientRect) {
      return null;
    }
    el.innerHTML = "x";
    el.style.cssText = "position:fixed;top:100px;";
    container.appendChild(el);
    var originalHeight = container.style.height, originalScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
    container.style.height = "3000px";
    container.scrollTop = 500;
    var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    container.style.height = originalHeight;
    var isSupported = elementTop === 100;
    container.removeChild(el);
    container.scrollTop = originalScrollTop;
    return isSupported;
  }
  return null;
}
```

If it runs, it works, if it doesn't, you'll get a null.

Comment: That's because IOS5 is a fickle woman. Please see the docs regarding [position:fixed and jQM's latest distribution](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/)

Comment: Is this the only known issue? Is it secure to use this method followed by an exception to iOS 5?

Comment: @Diogo You can only be certain of two things in life: `death and taxes`. That being said, it would seem that you're A.O.K. to create an exception for iOS5 considering `JQM's documentation`

Comment: Could you be a little more specific regarding to which functionalities of jQuery Mobile should I use when creating an exception to iOS 5?

Comment: `if(navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5(_\d)+ like Mac OS X/i) ){ alert('iOS5')}` see if that does the trick?

Comment: This code doesnt work on Android stock browser. On a new page view it causes the page to scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

```
var supportFixed = (function () {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.style.cssText = 'position:fixed';
    if (elem.style.position.match('fixed')) return true;
    return false;
}());
```

Comment: this seems like the best solution to me by far. i used jquery be safe.     var $test = $("<div style='display:none;'></div>");
    $("body").append($test);
    $test.css("position", "fixed");
    var supportFixed = $test.css("position") === "fixed";
    $test.remove();  --- but this didnt solve my issue. ios4 says that it supports fixed even though it doesn't.

Comment: Does give false positive on iPad because of its pseudo support of position:fixed

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work on mobile browsers?

```
function isFixedPositionSupported() {
   var e = document.createElement('div')
   try {
      e.style.position = 'fixed'
      return e.style.position == 'fixed'
   } catch (exception) {
      return false
   }
}
```

Comment: Work on firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Ohgodwhy's code is correct, but for iOS, you can check the user agent and see if it's the iOS Safari. Then return that it is supported. The user agent strings are

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

I'm not sure how to code this, but I'm sure this is what you need to do to detect iOS.

Comment: Device sniffing is not and will never be a reliable way to feature detect across all browsers.